# Restore server roles

Tags: sql-server

Someone messed up with the default windows login's server roles and removed sysadmin. I've lost lots of permissions and can't seem to restore them (Obviously because I've lost the privilege)

It's a default installation of SQL Server 2008 R2, no passwords set and there are no other logins, except for sa that doesn't seem to work.
I don't even know what to search for.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't specified a password during setup for the sa account then it is disabled by default.

You can try to [rebuild system databases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003(v=sql.110).aspx) with the correct admin account. 
To do this follow the steps in the link I gave you.

**EDIT**

[Add users in sysadmin role](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004(v=sql.110).aspx).

Comment: Do you have any errors? or after restoring you still don't see the user on the master database?

Comment: Reread my question please, it's server roles not user mappings, I'm still learning.

Comment: I, once, had to deal with a similar problem but in a cluster env. I'll update the answer with the article that helped me.